# Depurar información en la class win32

Tags: c#

Estoy extrayendo información con la class win32 de c#, pero hay información que no necesito y quiero eliminarla. Estoy ocupando el método listView1.Items.RemoveAt(0); 
PERO NO OCULTA LA INFORMACIÓN QUE YO NO DESEO 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTE ES EL CÓDIGO:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MuestraInformacion1("Win32_Processor");
    }


    private void MuestraInformacion1(String Key)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        // ************************************
        // Propiedades adicionadas al ListView
        // ************************************ 
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Propiedad");
        listView1.Columns.Add("Valor");

        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from " + Key);
            foreach (ManagementObject objeto in searcher.Get())
            {
                // ************************************
                // Se obtiene el key para el grupo adicionado
                // ************************************
                string grupo = objeto["Name"].ToString();
                listView1.Groups.Add(grupo, grupo);

                if (objeto.Properties.Count <= 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("La Información No Está Disponible", "No Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    return;
                }


                foreach (PropertyData PropiedadObjeto in objeto.Properties)
                {
                    ListViewItem listViewItem1 = new ListViewItem(PropiedadObjeto.Name);
                    if (PropiedadObjeto.Value != null && PropiedadObjeto.Value.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        listViewItem1.SubItems.Add(PropiedadObjeto.Value.ToString());
                    }
                    listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem1);

                    // ************************************
                    // Se adiciona el ListViewItem al Grupo creado anteriormente
                    // ************************************
                    listView1.Groups[grupo].Items.Add(listViewItem1);                     

                    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
                    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(1);
                    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(2);
                    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(3);
                    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(4);
                    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(5);


                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se pueden obtener datos \n" + exp.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }




}
```

}

UN EJEMPLO DE LA INFORMACIÓN QUE DESEO OCULTAR SERÍA LO QUE MARQUE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y cual es la informacion que deseas ocultar.. ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que tu problema está aqui:

```
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(1);
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(2);
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(3);
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(4);
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(5);
```

Con cada `RemoveAt`, el número de elementos en tu `ListView` está decreciendo, con lo que llega un momento en el que el indice que tratas de borrar probablemente no existe. Si lo que quieres es borrar los items con indices del 0 al 5, podrias hacer algo como:

```
for (int i=5;i>0;i--)
{
      listView1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

**Edit**

Tras analizar tu código y viendo la imagen de lo que quieres eliminar, el problema que tienes es donde te dije en mi respuesta original, pero el error que te da es porque ese codigo debes sacarlo del foreach, ya que la primera vez que añades un item ya intentas eliminar 6, lo que lógicamente te lanza una excepción. Así que la parte del foreach de tu código debe ser algo asi:

```
foreach (PropertyData PropiedadObjeto in objeto.Properties)
{
      ListViewItem listViewItem1 = new ListViewItem(PropiedadObjeto.Name);
      if (PropiedadObjeto.Value != null && PropiedadObjeto.Value.ToString() != "")
      {
            listViewItem1.SubItems.Add(PropiedadObjeto.Value.ToString());
      }
      listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem1);

      // ************************************
      // Se adiciona el ListViewItem al Grupo creado anteriormente
      // ************************************
      listView1.Groups[grupo].Items.Add(listViewItem1);                     
}
//Cuando ya hemos cargado todo,podemos eliminar los items que nos interese
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(1);
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(2);
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(3);
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(4);
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(5);
```

Comment: es verídico lo que comentas de hecho ya no aparecen algunos  datos, pero noto que no sigue un indice. quita los datos aleatorios no en especifico los deseados..

Comment: Para que te borre los que tu quieres,tienes que empezar a eliminar desde atras. Es decir,si quieres eliminar los elementos con indices 1,3 y 5,debes eliminar primero el 5,luego el 3 y finalmente el 1 @JohnnyGR

Comment: Si no,haz una lista con el texto de los elementos a eliminar,y elimina los items que contienen ese texto en lugar de usar los indices

Comment: oye muchísimas gracias